# WPF Popup in a DataGrid only closes when clicking on the datagrid header but not when clicking elsewhere

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm working on a WPF User Interface. I have a Popup in a DataGrid which is opened on the "MouseLeftButtonDown" event of a TextBlock and asks if the user is sure to delete the row. Until then it all works fine.
The problem is that the Popup only closes if I click on the header row of the datagrid. If I click elsewhere the popup does not close. The Property "StaysOpen" is already set false.
If I use the same XAML Code outside a Datagrid everything works fine.

How can I achieve that the popup closes?
btw I'm using MVVM pattern, so it would be great if solution is integrated in XAML Code.

My XAML Code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
<Storyboard
x:Key="OpenDeleteReadingPopup"
            BeginTime="0:0:0">
            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteReadingChoicesPopup"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame
                    KeyTime="00:00:00"
                    Value="true" />
            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel x:Name="OuterElement">
<toolkit:DataGrid
        ItemsSource="{Binding Readings}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReading}"
        IsReadOnly="False">

        <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
            <!-- other column-->
            <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Name="DeleteReadingTextBlock"
                                Margin="0 1 0 0"
                                FontFamily="Marlett"
                                Text="r"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBlock.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger
                                       RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                        <BeginStoryboard
                                            Storyboard="{StaticResource OpenDeleteReadingPopup}" />
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </TextBlock.Triggers>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <Popup
                                AllowsTransparency="True"
                                x:Name="DeleteReadingChoicesPopup"
                                StaysOpen="False"
                                Placement="Top"
                                PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=DeleteReadingTextBlock}">
                                <StackPanel
                                    Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundColorBrush}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Button 
                                        x:Name="Button"
                                        cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding ElementName=OuterElement, Path=DataContext}"
                                        Style="{DynamicResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
                                        cal:Message.Attach="DeleteReading($dataContext)"
                                        Content="{lex:Loc Sure}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Popup>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>

    </toolkit:DataGrid>

</StackPanel>
```